# Redundancy in Expression

Tags: american-english

Dear fellow stackexchangers, I would like to have your comment on the following, exercepted from a recent White House press conference… with Obama speaking:

"But there have been Republican Presidents with whom I disagreed with, but I didn’t have a doubt that they could function as President."

Shouldn't it be 'with whom I disagreed' rather than the above? Did Obama commit a grammatical redundancy in the above phrase?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, he made a mistake. The second *with* is superfluous and probably even makes the sentence non-grammatical. But it happens all the time. No big deal.

Comment: By the way, Obama gets it right elsewhere when he says "[change] requires listening to those *with whom you disagree*" (https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2016/05/07/remarks-president-howard-university-commencement-ceremony).

Comment: @Silenus No big deal? I'll bet there's a House committee looking into whether it's an impeachable offense.

Comment: OMG!  Impeachment time!  (It needs to be remembered that this is *spoken* language -- off-the-cuff, as it were.  There is no editor checking the syntax.  Most people would get tongue-tied in such situations, but Obama has always been somewhat remarkable in his ability to cogently string together words, regardless of how you may regard his politics.)

Comment: He also says "is is". I've come to terms with it.

Comment: Either at the front or at the end, not both. But it's an easy mistake to make; if you've forgotten that you pied-piped the _with_ when you fronted the relative pronoun, it may seem safer to put it in. That's why pied-piping is always optional, and preposition stranding is much much more common.